# Change a specific column in table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Trying to get a record from list of records in a table.  In each each record I have a field `status` which is set to be 1. Here I am showing only one record in the `View` and a `Button`. When I click on a button it has to change the status of that record to 3 in database and then get the another record in the same view. Presently I have created this view by selecting Scaffolding template List.

**Controller :**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    dbSampleEntities db = new dbSampleEntities ();
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = db.Visits.Where(x=> x.Status == "1").OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1);
        return View(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeStatus(int VisitorID)
    {           
         return RedirectToAction("Index");         
    }
}
```

**Index.html :**

```
 @model IEnumerable<SampleApp.Visit>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VisitorID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VisitTypeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BranchID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserCreated)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedTime)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VisitorID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VisitTypeID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BranchID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserCreated)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStatus", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.VisitorID)
                    <input type="submit" value="Change Status" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Here `ChangeStatus` is calling but getting null values. Help me where I am mistaken.

Comment: try changing your `return View();` to `return RedirectToAction('Index')` in `ChangeStatus`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that. But in that POST method I have to update the status column from 1 to 3. But I am getting all values are null in **ChangeStatus(Visit visit)**

Answer (score 1):

The form is posting to `ChangeStatus`, but there are no *form values* being posted.  There's no data to post because the form has no actual form elements.  So the framework has no values from which to construct an instance of `Visit`.

Since you're just performing a single predefined operation on a record, all you really need is an *identifier* for that record.  You don't need the entire record.  With that identifier you will get the record from the database, update it, and save it.

So remove the overall form and add one for each table row, and therein you would include a form element for the identifier:

```
<td>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStatus", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.VisitorID)
        <input type="submit" value="Change Status" />
    }
</td>
```

(Note: I'm *guessing* that `VisitorID` is the identifier for the record.  Though the naming doesn't quite line up 100%.  Use whatever identifier, or set of identifiers, exists for that record.)

Then in the action just expect the identifier:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeStatus(int visitorID)
{
    // use the visitorID to fetch the record that you want to update
    return RedirectToAction('Index')
}
```

Comment: Tried as you said. But getting this error                                                                          **The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ChangeStatus(Int32)' in 'NiranjanApp.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

Comment: @NNR: Show what you tried.  The name of the parameter and the name of the form element have to match, that's how the framework knows to use them.

Comment: Updated my question with changes

Comment: @NNR: Interesting.  And the error is looking for the parameter `id`, but there isn't a parameter by that name?  What is the URL of the POST request being generated in the `form` element?  Maybe try renaming the method parameter from `VisitorID` to just `id`?  Mostly a guess.